# Difference between three terminologies

Tags: criminal-law, contract-law

I have confused many times wherever I studied about “Dacoity, Robbery and Extortion”. These three terms are closely related to each other and written in ambiguous forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Robbery** is a theft achieved through the use of violence or a threat of violence.

**[Dacoity](http://devgan.in/ipc/chapter_17.php#s391)** -- which I'd never heard of before -- is robbery by a group of at least five people. The term appears to be used only in India and maybe some nearby countries, but other countries may have equivalents. In the United States, for instance, that conduct would often lead to liability under our [criminal street gang](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/521) statute.

**Extortion** is the use of illegal means (such as violence or coercion) to obtain something or to force someone to do something.

Robbery and extortion can start to look like the same thing when dealing with threats rather than actual violence. In those cases, distinguish between the two by looking for:

1. a threat of violence,
2. a threat of violence in the *immediate* future; and
3. a threat contingent on a refusal to surrender property.

If any one of those is missing, you're probably dealing with extortion rather than robbery.

Answer (score 1):

**Extortion**: Do what I want or I will do these bad things to you.

**Robbery**: *Give* me what I want **now** or I will do these bad things to you **now**.

**Dacoity** — same as robbery, but done by a gang.